# How to swap comma and dot in a string

Tags: python, string

I am fetching price from a site in format: 10.990,00 which does not make sense as such. What is needed to make it as 10,990.00. I tried following but it's replacing all.

```
price = "10.990,00"
price = price.replace(',','.',1)
price = price.replace('.',',',1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The existing answers do a good job of answering your question, but taking a step back, what are you trying to accomplish? If you're trying to "fetch prices from a site and display them in your local currency, regardless of the source currency," you might benefit from converting the price to a number, then using your locale to display the price properly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8421922/how-do-i-convert-a-currency-string-to-a-floating-point-number-in-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606517/python-how-to-format-currency-string

Comment: Of course, my suggestion above doesn't account for currency conversion... but that's a whole other issue...

Comment: The site I am scraping mistakenly swapped commas and dots.

Comment: @Volatil3: while it could be a mistake, it's worth remembering that not everyone on Earth uses the same comma/period conventions for formatting numbers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are replacing the *first* dot with a comma, after first replacing the first comma with a dot. The dot the first `str.replace()` inserted is not exempt from being replaced by the second `str.replace()` call.

Use the [`str.translate()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) instead:

```
try:
    from string import maketrans   # Python 2
except ImportError:
    maketrans = str.maketrans      # Python 3

price = price.translate(maketrans(',.', '.,'))
```

This'll swap commas for dots and vice versa as it traverses the string, and won't make double replacements, and is *very fast* to boot.

I made the code compatible with both Python 2 and 3, where [`string.maketrans()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.maketrans) was replaced by a the [static `str.maketrans()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans).

The exception here is Python 2 `unicode`; it works the same as `str.translate()` in Python 3, but there is no `maketrans` factory to create the mapping for you. You can use a dictionary for that:

```
unicode_price = unicode_price.translate({u'.': u',', u',': u'.'})
```

Demo:

```
>>> try:
...     from string import maketrans   # Python 2
... except ImportError:
...     maketrans = str.maketrans      # Python 3
... 
>>> price = "10.990,00"
>>> price.translate(maketrans(',.', '.,'))
'10,990.00'
```

Comment: It's interesting I am on Py27 and it says `Uresolved Reference` for `maketrans`

Comment: @Volatil3: that sounds like your IDE is telling you that; is it PyCharm? You can just use the first line without the `try..except` and PyCharm will not complain anymore, or you could just ignore that warning; the IDE sees the `maketrans = str.maketrans` line and doesn't know it will never be executed on Python 2.

Comment: Yes it's PyCharm :-) let me run then

Comment: For python2, I'd add a note that this won't work for unicode strings (e.g. they're getting `price` from some json).

Comment: @georg: at which point you'd have to use your own dictionary: `{u'.': u',', u',': u'.'}`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am getting: ` type object 'str' has no attribute 'mktrans'`

Comment: @MartijnPieters is it `maketrans`?

Comment: @Volatil3: it is maketrans, I mistyped the name before.

Comment: So, you ended up with `try... import-maketrans-thing.... if unicode translate-with-dict else translate-with-maketrans ` - 8 lines in total. A bit too much for the OP's problem, isn't it? ;)

Comment: @georg: only if you are going to re-use the code in this answer for something that must work with both `str` and `unicode` in Python 2, and `str` in Python 3 all in one codebase. But I now at least covered all the bases.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your code doesn't work is because you convert `10.990,00` to `10.990.00` and then you are replacing **all** dots with comma.

Instead you can convert `,` to a symbol then convert `.` to `,` and the symbol to `.` :

```
price = "10.990,00"
price = price.replace(',','COMMA')
price = price.replace('.',',')

price = price.replace('COMMA','.')

print(price)
```

Or as suggested by [georg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29036023/how-to-swap-comma-and-dot-in-a-string/29036080#comment46313002_29036080)

```
price = price.replace(',','COMMA').replace('.',',').replace('COMMA','.')
```

Note that i removed the optional argument in `replace()`, since numbers like `1.200.000,30` would not convert as expected.

Comment: You actually don't need the "COMMA" thing here, just `price.replace('.','@').replace(',','.').replace('@',',')`

Comment: It would be a big trouble if OP had to exchange 3 characters, 4 characters and so on  :D

Comment: @Heisenberg I agree, but since he only mentions `,` and `.` this solution would be ok. Creating an answer based on further assumptions might make it unnecessarily complex.

Answer (score 3):

@Martijn has given the best answer. you can also iterate over the `price` and `replace`.

```
swap = {'.':',',',':'.'}
def switchDotsAndCommas(text):
    text = ''.join(swap.get(k, k) for k in text)
    print text

switchDotsAndCommas('10.990,00')
```

Comment: This is essentially what `str.translate()` *does*. But way, way faster.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is it faster due to some other algo being used or something else?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yeah, but this is more generalizable, and uses a pattern which comes in handy in many other contexts as well.  It's worth knowing about.

Comment: @DSM - it is as same as `list compression` is much faster than creating a list by iterating over other list as LC is entirely done in `C`. (I guess).

Answer (score 0):

May be this is a long answer but it is simple to execute and doesn't use any built in function:

```
l=input("enter the input:")
m=[]
for i in l:
 if(i=='.'):
  m.append(',')
 elif(i==','):
  m.append('.')
 else:
  m.append(i)
print(''.join(m))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
price = "10.990,00"
price = price.replace(',','.')
price1=price[0:3].replace('.',',')
print(price1+price[3:9])
```

Comment: this won't work for larger numbers (ex. "100.990,00" will result in "100.990.0")

Comment: Please explain your answer - add some text around it.